# Is it possible to change how usernames are displayed on an AD bound CentOS system?

Tags: centos, active-directory

I don't even know if such a thing is even possible. I'm not referring to the bash shell customization.

On an Active Directory bound CentOS 7 system, a local user account will just show as **username** but an AD account is shown like **username@domain.whatever@hostname**. Can these be converted to just the username portion?

It just makes for very long output on file permissions and so forth.

Example: an `ls -al` in my home directory will show

`-rw-------. 1 username@domain.com domain users@domain.com 512 Jan 22 11:09 .bash_profile`

I understand the system needs to be able to differentiate between a local user or domain user but just curious how other people work with this.

Comment: What software are you using to bind the Cent system to AD?

Comment: Forgot to include that. I used realm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a similar thing I complained about because I only have one domain, I don't have multiple domains. In a scenario like that, having the domain names on the user's is pretty useful. But... we don't want that, right?

Change your `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` to have these lines under your `[domain...]` stanza.

```
use_fully_qualified_names = False
```

Restart sssd. I usually clear the cache first just in case.

```
service sssd stop
rm -rf /var/lib/sss/db/*
service sssd start
```

And then try again. The `getent` command should report back correctly afterwards.

```
[lleba@bro-mg-01 ~]$ getent passwd lleba@bromosapien.net
lleba:*:10000:10000:Louis L:/home/lleba:/bin/bash
[lleba@bro-mg-01 ~]$ getent passwd lleba
lleba:*:10000:10000:Louis L:/home/lleba:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks for your continued help Sokel (I'm still playing with changing access control to sssd btw). After I made the changes you indicated above my domain accounts were no longer allowed to connect. /var/log/secure shows sshd[14929]: input_userauth_request: invalid user username@domain.com [preauth] then pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname... and pam_sss received for user username@domain.com: 17 (Failure setting user credentials) and finally a Failed password for invalid user. My username@domain.com also doesn't show in passwd either. Do I need to prestage domain users?

Comment: That's interesting. Try putting sssd in debug mode, clean the cache and restart the service and see what the logs give you /var/log/sssd. There's debug_level I think you can set. Do you mind presenting your whole sssd.conf on fpaste?

Comment: I enabled as much logging as I could (without going super ultra verbose) and it wasn't logging the deny access. My sssd.conf is here: http://ur1.ca/og80b I changed the actual domain name to domain.com. I'm wondering if I have conflicting authentication systems working together...

Comment: Additional info Sokel, I'm not sure I have sssd configured properly or even bound the system to AD properly because I'm reading documents now about trusting AD certs which I never did. [Troubleshooting SSSD](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/SSSD-Troubleshooting.html#idp17015328) Do you have a proper guide for CentOS and Active Directory? I see your bio talks about this.

Comment: Most of my write-ups are directly with LDAP and not necessarily with AD. Those ldapsearch commands are usually if you plan on doing those against the directory itself. SSSD handles this transparently in combination with samba calls and kerberos. See the following paste of what I do to add a system to AD. http://www.fpaste.org/314684/53761339/

Comment: Thanks again Sokel. Today I blew away the VM and did it again from scratch with what I've learned and it all works now the way I want. Your answer was the correct one and works great.